# MYSQL, problema com caracteres importando csv

Tags: mysql, csv, acentuação

Estou passando a base de dados Maxmind csv para mysql e alguns caracteres acentuados estão dando problema. Em *Latin* aparece um `?` e em *UTF* não aparece nada.

```
CSV   : Östra Frölunda
UTF8  :
LATIN1: ?stra Fr?lunda
```

Usei o código abaixo que encontrei em um site para importar todo o ficheiro:

```
CREATE TABLE  `location` (
  `locID` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `country` char(2) default NULL,
  `region` char(2) default NULL,
  `city` varchar(45) default NULL,
  `postalCode` char(7) default NULL,
  `latitude` double default NULL,
  `longitude` double default NULL,
  `dmaCode` char(3) default NULL,
  `areaCode` char(3) default NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`locID`),
  KEY `Index_Country` (`country`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 ROW_FORMAT=FIXED;

load data infile 'GeoLiteCity-Location.csv' 
into table `location` 
fields terminated by ',' optionally enclosed by '"' 
lines terminated by '\n' 
ignore 2 lines;
```

O csv tem outras cidades com caracteres ilegíveis, mas estes nem vou me importar no momento, mas queria importar do jeito que está para depois sanitizar.

Comment: Como você determinou que o CSV era latin1 para escolher o charset? Uma das primeiras coisas seria avaliar corretamente o CSV (antes mesmo de importar).

Comment: Pelo que vi em outro site, o arquivo é iso. Todos exemplos que vi o charset é latin1... o unico que vi como UTF fazia a conversão do arquivo.

Comment: Latin 1 é o iso-8859-1 (praticamente). Mas sem ter certeza, fica complicado. A melhor coisa é olhar num editor de código pra ter certeza, ou mesmo abrir o CSV como texto num browser que tenha opção manual de codificação pra vc testar qual funciona. Pra quem tem um editor hexadecimal à mão também basta olhar os bytes. Sem determinar o charset correto, vai ficar tudo na base do chute (e uma resposta que sirva pro seu caso pode não servir pra mais ninguém).

Comment: O próprio código PHP do Maxmind que trabalha com o .DAT, define o uso do ISO: `mb_internal_encoding('ISO-8859-1')`. Por isso acredito que os outros files sejam iso também, mas de qualquer maneira, depois eu tento descobrir com mais eficiencia qual charset.

Comment: Grande chance de ser, e neste caso, mesmo que seja, precisa ver como é que você está conferindo os dados na tela (uma coisa é salvar errado no DB, outra é visualizar)

Comment: Mas se o charset fosse o mesmo não seria gravado igual ao csv?

Comment: 1) carega o CSV num editor de texto
2) verifica se os caracteres são OK
3) se não, modifica o sistema de código (por ex. Latin1, UTF...) para ter os caracteres coreto
4) Salva usando UTF-8
5) Cria a tabela de dados usando Charset=utf8_general_ci

Comment: @PapaCharlie Considere comentar nesta pergunta a situação atual e até talvez, contribuir com uma resposta se caso já resolveu.

Comment: @ismael, o csv da Maxmind estava incompleto e apresentava alguns erros - além de não converter os caracteres corretamente. Resolvi abandonar a versão free.